# Deleting features in one layer causes changes to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, debugging

I had two identical layers in a map (one original and one copy). I noticed two features in the attribute table of the copy layer not related to any polygons on the map, which I deleted. This caused 3 apparently unrelated features to be deleted in both the copy and original layer.

What could have caused this?

Some notes:
-QGIS version is 3.18

- Both layers are saved as separate shapefiles. neither is a temporary scratch layer.
- There was an error code, however I didn't write it down at the time.

Comment: When you say 'copy layer', did you actually export as a separate file or just duplicate it in the layers panel? What is the geometry type of your layers? When you say apparently unrelated, are you sure they are not multi-part polygons?

Comment: I suppose that exactly what @Ben_W mentioned happeney in your case. Try fixing this or share your project + data (including project file and **all** data files, including the shapefile sidecar files).